# Change Dual Monitor Behavior

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

When you setup dual monitors, to move a windows to a different display (monitor), you move it sideways (right or left). Is it possible to change the behavior to move the window by moving vertically, i.e. up or down.

I have two monitors setup in a special case above each other (instead or side by side). I want to make it easier by dragging windows up and down instead of sideways since it happens to be confusing.

I am using Windows 8.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the windows control pannel "Display", go to the resolution section

[image]

With the mouse Click on and drag the visual represenation of the monitors, into the desired configuration.

Comment: So... what did you do? I was under the impression you could just drag them into position.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : I wasn't aware of that initially. :( Later I figured it out that I could drag them.

Comment: True, that wasn't obvious in your original answer.